# ADWLauncher: Go straight to default screen instead of requiring a second "home" tap?

Tags: home-screen, adw.launcher

I have CM7 installed, and am using ADWLauncher which comes pre-installed.

I know how to configure a "default" home screen, so that when I'm in ADWLauncher already, pressing "home" brings me to the default screen.  But when I'm in another application, pressing "home" takes me to the most recently viewed screen, and an additional tap of "home" is required to then move to the default screen.  What I want to do is be able to press "home" from ANY application and go STRAIGHT to the default screen, regardless of what my last viewed screen was.  Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a setting in ADW that can do that. I use ADW.EX and I looked through all the settings and didn't see any way to achieve what your are asking for.

It is, however, open source, so someone could implement the option for this, or you could request it to [anderweb](http://jbthemes.com/anderweb) and he might add it to an update.